# Getting text of <select> <option> with jQuery not producing 'normal' results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been racking my brain trying to figure out what is causing the line of code below not to behave 'normally':

```
$('#country option:selected').text()
```

To be clear, I have tried multiple ways of getting the output of the option tag with no luck..
I am using `.text()` because of previous posts but it only returns a blank string.
What I am attempting to do, is send form data to a plain text file.
I have tried the below code with no luck as well:

```
$('#country option').text()
$('#country option').val()
$('#country option:selected').val()
```

I have included a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/vulpcod3z/pen/KDJby) to assist with the problem.
Might I also include that this uses php to load in a list of countries from a file that loads in 197 countries.. I have only included 2 (through normal HTML) in my Pen in order to help reproduce my issue.
On the second page, select a country from the dropdown and proceed to the last page. It will say `Submit Hopefully..`. Open your browser's console and then click the button.This will produce the blank string. What it should be producing is the country selected. I have tried this in simple setups and it works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: The selected `<option>`s value becomes the `.value` of the `<select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id is missing in `<select name="country">`. So your `<select>` should look like this

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <!--<?php require_once( 'php/countries.php' ); ?>-->
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
```

If you want value from select

```
country = $('#country').val()
```

or if you want text of selected option

```
text = $('#country option:selected').text()
```

Comment: It is never needed/beneficial to repeat an option's text as its `value` attribute -- just omit the unneeded `value` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$('#country').val()
```

And add this to your select element.

```
id="country"
```

Comment: This produces `undefined`

Comment: Excuse me. I was looking at this on mobile and I missed that last code block of yours.. it does work

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your Select and values to your options

```
<select  id="country" name="country">
     <!--<?php require_once( 'php/countries.php' ); ?>-->
     <option value="US">US</option>
     <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
```

Then in your object set country to the #country value

```
var formData = { 
      name: $('input#name').val(), 
      add1: $('input#add1').val(), 
      add2: $('input#add2').val(), 
      city: $('input#city').val(),
      state: $('input#state').val(),
      country: $('#country').val()
    }
```

Finally...

```
$('#country').val()
```

Will be your country Name

Comment: Thanks. This works too, but I wanted to do this with the `.text()` function to save having to add the values.